# Why is this Python package trying to use a non-existent gcc?

Tags: software-installation, gcc

I'm trying to install PyCrypto for Python 3 on Solaris.  Whether I do it via "`python3 setup.py install`" or "`pip3 install pycrypto`", I run into the same problem: a call is made to a gcc which does not exist:

```
python3 setup.py install
[...]
/opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8 -pipe -m32 -march=pentiumpro -Wno-unused-result -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -pipe -m32 -march=pentiumpro -I/usr/include/gmp -fPIC -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/opt/csw/include/python3.3m -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.solaris-2.11-i86pc.32bit-3.3/src/_fastmath.o
unable to execute /opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8: No such file or directory
```

Now, I know nothing about the history of the machine that I'm on.  It's possible that /opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8 existed at some point in the past.  But it doesn't anymore.  `export CC=/usr/bin/gcc` *(or some other gcc) does NOT fix the problem* --- without fail /opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8 is called.

I'm less interested in installing PyCrypto and more interested in understanding **WHY** this bogus call is made to begin with.  Where is the value "/opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8" saved?  How/where does the system even get the information to think that it needs to call that compiler?

The only thing I can think of is that Python3 was originally compiled with /opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8, and Python3 has it permanently burned in somewhere that /opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8 is the compiler to use for compiling stuff.  If this is the case, would I be best off removing and re-installing Python3 to get rid of this erroneous dependence?

Comment: I would guess that it might have something to do with `distutils`? Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967065/python-distutils-not-using-correct-version-of-gcc

Comment: I suggest a pointer to the source? Alternatively, look at or paste `setup.py` to start with.

Comment: setup.py contents here: https://github.com/dlitz/pycrypto/blob/master/setup.py No direct reference to gcc.  But "build" is part of "distutils" so maybe @jmunsch is in the right direction.

Comment: distutils.sysconfig seems to indicate that it should respect the CC environmental variable :/

Comment: Just to be sure you do not use `sudo`, do you?

Comment: Right, I'm running this as root directly, not issuing a sudo command.

Comment: what's the output of `export`? Also, can you add the lines prior to the error?

Comment: It should be important also to add the output of `pip install -v pycrypto`

Answer (score 1):

`/opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8` path indicates for OpenCSW that comes pre-installed with Oracle distro (either 4.8 is deleted or there is another version).

Try setting the `CC` and `CXX` environment variables from inside `setup.py` with `os.environ`:

```
os.environ["CC"] = "g++-4.7" os.environ["CXX"] = "g++-4.7"
```

(4.7 is my version of `g++`, set it to what you have in your `/bin`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a soft link at `/opt/csw/bin/gcc-4.8` that points to your `cc` or `gcc` compiler, maybe?

Comment: This is more of a question than an answer. Please review: [How do I write a good answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). And update your answer with maybe some examples and more of an explanation. Thanks.

Comment: That is unlikely to work as the `gcc` commandline options are different. A script that throws away the gcc-specific options and then calls the available compiler might work though.

Comment: @DevNull How is this a question? It seems like it would work fine, albeit a bit hacky

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, yeah it might. But it seems more like WayneB is asking OP to try to create a soft link `maybe?`, than showing how to create such a link and how it might help. I retract my comment if I'm the only one that feels that way.